# cant run executable (application/x-executable)

Tags: executable

I am a new Ubuntu user and I want to stream my system sound on my phone via usb. I downloaded soundwire which is a program that allows us to do this. I tested it on my other linux distro and was able to run it. But I can't run it in Ubuntu. Its "executable (program/x-executable)" file. please help me .

Comment: its the soundwire application download link so you can try it by yourself:
```https://georgielabs.net/```

Comment: Hi POT! Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! To help us help you accurately, we need you to elaborate on "I can't in Ubuntu", with specifics. What did you do, and what happened instead?

Comment: i meant im not able to run the program in ubuntu but was able to run it in another linux distro

Comment: It is likely that if we try it, it will work fine. The less work you make people do, the more they are likely to help you. You are not being specific when you say "I'm not able to run the program." That's extremely vague and we can't help you unless you give us the exact steps you took in excruciating and exact detail. Thanks!

Comment: with my other linux distro , i downloaded the soundwire linux version and double clicked on the ```executable (program/x-executable)``` file and opened the application . on ubuntu i downloaded the exact program and now i cant open it . when i click on it nothing happens

Comment: Ok, that is helpful; thank you. SoundWire appears to require extensive setup; did you follow the steps in `INSTALL.txt`?

Comment: no :( . im beginner and those methods was hard to undrestand . i didnt follow any of those steps in my other linux distro but was able to run and thats why im confused ...

Comment: Also, which version of Ubuntu are you using, and did you download the 32-bit or 64-bit version of the program? What filename did you download? It should appear in your browser's Download History. Thanks!

Comment: You said you "double clicked on the executable (`program/x-executable`) file and opened the application". I'm a little confused about the `program/x-executable` part. The files on the page you supplied are `tar.gz` archives, not `program/x-executable` files, and I'm not sure where you found out this file was a `program/x-executable` type of file. Even if you double clicked on the `tar.gz` file you downloaded, on my system, there are no `program/x-executable` file types listed, only an `unknown` type for `SoundWireServer`. Is that the file you clicked on?

Comment: no i extracted the folder and double clicked on ```executable (program/x-executable)``` file . it worked on my other linux distro and loaded the program but not working on ubuntu .

Comment: yes i clicked on ```SoundwireServer``` its ```executable (program/x-executable)``` isnt it ?

Comment: Ok, good, you extracted the folder. Ok, yes, it's important to know you clicked on `SoundWireServer`; thanks. Have you used a terminal before (`Ctrl`-`Alt`-`T`)?

Comment: yes i know some basic command

Comment: Cool! Ok, open a terminal and use the `cd` command (e.g. `cd ~/Downloads/SoundWireServer`) to navigate to the directory where you extracted the files. (Make sure you actually extracted them by clicking on `Extract` or using `tar` from the command-line, rather than just viewing the archive by double-clicking on it in the desktop.) This directory I expected ends in `SoundWireServer`. From that directory, type `./SoundWireServer`, and tell me what it outputs.

Comment: i extracted on my desktop with GUI . opened the archive file and used ```extract``` button so i changed my directory to ```~/Desktop/SoundWireServer``` and typed ```./SoundWireServer``` . and its the error : ```./SoundWireServer: error while loading shared libraries: libportaudio.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory```

Comment: Got it. Hang on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think once you install PortAudio, and maybe `libqt5widgets5`, `firewall-config`, and `pavucontrol` just to be sure, per the `INSTALL.txt` instructions, it should work (you will need to issue these from the Terminal [`Ctrl`-`Alt`-`T`], and type your password in):

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install -y libportaudio2 libqt5widgets5 pavucontrol firewall-config
```

You'll need to reconfigure your firewall per the instructions. Launch Firewall from the GUI (typing your password in again), click on the Ports tab, click `Add`, and for `Port/Port Range` type `59010-59011`, and change the `Protocol` to `UDP` and click `OK`. Go to the top and change `Configuration` to `Permanent`.

Now launch SoundWireServer from the terminal just to make sure it runs. A window should come up and give a Server Address and say `Status: Disconnected`. Bring the app up on your phone and hit the button with the logo; you may have to enter the server address the server supplies. Then the `Status` should change to `Connected`.

From then on, you can launch SoundWireServer the way you attempted before. You can quit the version running on the Terminal first by typing `Ctrl`-`C`.

Comment: P.S. This definitely works over a local WiFi network, say at home. It says it will work over a 4G/5G network, but I don't see how.

Comment: thaaaaanks :DDD it worked . omg thank you so much dude...

Comment: You're welcome; my pleasure. If you could mark the question as Accepted (this is a check mark to the left of the answer), that's thanks enough!